# Display image after selecting file

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, image-uploading

I am trying to display the selected image in file input via JavaScript. Here is the code I used shown below:

```
<label id="lblFileUploadProfile">
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="ImageProfileUpload"   />
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="ImgProfilePic" ImageUrl="img/user-5.png"  />
```

I use this file input to upload image but have no idea how to display selected image when selecting image? 
how do i display it just when the upload is done useing JS ?

Comment: By using ajax.. Did you try anything?

Comment: Start with learning how to use google, there are plenty of examples already. The basic principle looks like this - you initiate the upload using ajax and the return values are two (or more) - if the upload succeeded and the path to the uploaded image. Then just update the src of the image...

Comment: okay thanks, but I don't know why are you so mad about it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
<img id="blah" class="photo" ImageUrl="img/user-5.png" />
<label for="imgInp" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i>Add Image
</label>
<input type='file' id="imgInp" name="image" />


<script>
//Preview & Update an image before it is uploaded
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function () {
        readURL(this);
    });
</script>


<style type="text/css">
input[type="file"] {
     display: none;
}

.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid rgb(197, 197, 197);
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;

    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: right;
    width: 5.25em;
    margin-left:200px;
}

.photo{
    width: 7em; 
    height: 9em; 
    border: 1px solid rgb(197, 197, 197); 
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px; 
    float:right;
}
</style>
```

Comment: you sure this worked with you ?

Comment: I use this in my MVC project and works perfectly. Please try this and let me know if it works.

Comment: I'm not using MVC, I'm using Empty website, and it didn't work with me 
It open the selection dialog but it do nothing when I select an Image

Comment: It does not make any sense to use Empty web site or MVC. It should work. Check the names and id's. Then integrate my example to your project. It should work.

Comment: On the other hand, the only problem may be ralated to "ImageUrl". I use "src" property instead of this but maybe this would work as well.

Comment: I don't have enough repetitions to vote up  :'(

Comment: Are you sure? Try again :)